# How can I send two values with one button?

Tags: php, forms, get, submit-button

Is it possible to submit two values from one button?

```
$orderby = $_GET['orderby'];

<form action="mypage.php" method="get">
<a><button name ="orderby" value="name" type="submit">&#9660;</button></a>
<a><button name ="orderby" value="age" type="submit">&#9660;</button></a>
</form>
```

I imagine something like this:

```
<a><button name ="orderby" value1="name" value2="ASC" type="submit">&#9660;</button></a>
<a><button name ="orderby" value1="name" value2="DESC" type="submit">&#9660;</button></a>
<a><button name ="orderby" value1="age" value2="ASC" type="submit">&#9660;</button></a>
<a><button name ="orderby" value1="age" value2="DESC" type="submit">&#9660;</button></a>
```

Comment: What would the benefit of that be?
The button only has a value such that you can distinguish different buttons. If you need to store a value temporarily on the client side, consider using a hidden field in your form.

Comment: no you can now, put value like value="name1,name2" and explode value with ",", you can get

Comment: just use value="name ASC", it will solve it easily for this case. More complicated cases could be solved sending delimited as @BrijalSavaliya suggested above. Or act native and use hidden elements.

Comment: keep all needed variables in hidden is best solution

Comment: @Jarla, You can use the `$orderby` itself as the value. And order by contain the `name_asc`.

Comment: @Jarla why you want to do it like this , keep it as "smozgur" suggested  value="name ASC" ,  value="name DESC".. so on ..

Comment: @FrayneKonok hello :) thank you, yes, I think I will do so, I was just wondering if there is a smarter solution

Comment: @BrijalSavaliya Yes, I think I have to do it like this, I thought, there is maybe a possibility to submit the values I need directly with one submit button

Comment: @Jarla, from where the `$orderby` comes from? What should be the value and can i use this in the form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a hidden field with `<input type="hidden"/>`:

```
<?php
    $orderby = $_GET['orderby'];
?>
<form action="mypage.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="field" value="fieldname"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="orderby" value="<?= $orderby ?>"/>
    <button name ="submit" value="1" type="submit">&#9660;</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to to use inside the form

```
<form>
<input type=hidden name=var1 value="value1">
<input type=hidden name=var2 value="value2">
<input type=hidden name=var3 value="value3">
```

Comment: I have multiple submit buttons in one form

Answer (score 2):

Send it through the URL eg.

```
<form action="mypage.php?orderby=name&order=ASC" method="get">
<a><button name ="orderby" value="name" type="submit">&#9660;</button></a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the button for get values, you can use jquery and ajax. A sample code is given below

```
$(form).on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var value1 = $('button[name=orderby]').attr('value1');
    var value2 = $('button[name=orderby]').attr('value2');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'your/url',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            value1: value1,
            value2: value2
        },
        success: function(data){
            //success action
        },
        error: function(){
            //error action
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like "`name ASC`" or "`name{splitter}ASC`" and explode it to use in your code

```
<a><button name ="orderby" value="name ASC" type="submit">&#9660;</button></a>
<a><button name ="orderby" value="name DESC" type="submit">&#9660;</button></a>
<a><button name ="orderby" value="age ASC" type="submit">&#9660;</button></a>
<a><button name ="orderby" value="age DESC" type="submit">&#9660;</button></a>
```

Comment: Thats usefull if you have a FORM and you need to submit in a FORM another two or more values and you cant create another FORM in the existing FORM.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the best way for your problem. This is something called smarter and dynamic for programmer.

You can do something like this:

**HTML Form**

```
<form action="mypage.php" method="get">
    <input type="radio" name="field" checked value="name"> Name
    <input type="radio" name="field" value="age"> Age<br/><br/>

    <input type="radio" name="order" checked value="desc"> DESC
    <input type="radio" name="order" value="asc"> ASC<br/><br/>

    <a><button name="orderby" value="orderby" type="submit">&#9660;</button></a>
</form>
```

**mypage.php**

Must use `isset` submit and other security.

```
$field = $_GET['field'];
$order = $_GET['order'];
```

Now all set just make what ever you want with them.